# com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.IllegalPdfSyntaxException: Unbalanced begin/end text operators

Tags: java, itext

Struggling with this problem in iText with PdfContentByte. When I try to create new page I'm using below code-

```
           canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
           canvas.saveState();


           canvas.stroke();
           canvas.restoreState();
         ...
            canvas.endText();
            itextDocument.newPage();

            setUpperFontAndSize(canvas);
            canvas.beginText();
```

The issue is occurring at the time of calling endText(). Is there any solution for it??

Comment: can you post code from creating canvas to `canvas.endText();`?

Comment: The exception is thrown because you would otherwise create a PDF that contains illegal syntax as demonstrated in the following question: [PDFs generated using itextsharp giving error at the time of first print command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21301497/pdfs-generated-using-itextsharp-giving-error-at-the-time-of-first-print-command) This is a question that was selected for [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](https://leanpub.com/itext_so).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OP says

> The issue is occurring at the time of calling endText()

According to the source code of that method, the exception in question indicates that there was no matching `beginText()` call before.

> > A text object begins with the **BT** operator and ends with the **ET** operator, as shown in the Example, and described in Table 107.
> >
> > EXAMPLE
> >
> > ```
> > BT
> > …Zero or more text operators or other allowed operators…
> > ET
> > ```
> >
> > ... text objects cannot be statically nested ...

Comment: Ah, we answered almost simultaneously ;-)

Comment: @BrunoLowagie ;) Fortunately `IllegalPdfSyntaxException: Unbalanced begin/end text operators` is easier to assess than `IllegalPdfSyntaxException: Unbalanced save/restore state operators`...

Answer (score 2):

Your code snippet is not complete. We see that you use:

```
canvas.endText();
```

As such, that statement is illegal and it is normal that you get an exception, because you can only use `endText()` after you have first used:

```
canvas.beginText();
```

In your code snippet, we only see `beginText()` *after* you have triggered `endText()`.

Also be aware that a `BT`/`ET` text object (an object that you create when you introduce a `beginText()`/`endText()` sequence) "lives" on a page. A text object can not "span" multiple pages.

For instance, this would be illegal:

```
canvas.beginText();
// do stuff
document.newPage();
canvas.endText();
```

The `BT`/`ET` pair should occur on the same page:

```
canvas.beginText();
// do stuff
canvas.endText();
document.newPage();
```